# C# Application compromises cookie data when two or more concurrent sessions are run

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, forms-authentication

**Background**

I have an application where users can log in and enter their time details. And I recently introduced a new table via which we can distinguish the users from different companies. Users can edit/view/update/delete their own company entries. 
The database looks like this

```
COMPANY  ---  STAFF  --  TIMESHEET  --  PROJECTS
```

All these tables are connected via foreign keys.

I am using C#, ASP.NET, ADO.NET, SQL Server to run this application, I am storing `companyId` in user authentication cookie upon login and then matching that key everywhere to match with the database.

**My issue**

Whenever I run two instances of localhost, and I click on the same page together, data from different company id is being shown to me.

**Edit:** adding more code:

Code to get company id from authentication cookie:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket.UserData))
    companyId = Convert.ToInt32(logB.GetCompanyId(email));
else
{
      try
      {
          companyId = Convert.ToInt32(ticket.UserData);
      }
      catch
      {
          companyId = Convert.ToInt32(logB.GetCompanyId(email));
      }
}
```

Using that `companyId` to get staff details

```
public void GetCustomerData(string email)
{
        StaffBLL staff = user.GetStaff(email, companyId);

        if (staff != null)
        {
            name.InnerText = staff.Name + " " + staff.LastName;
        }
        else 
            Response.Redirect("../error/500");
}
```

ADO.NET code:

```
if (myConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    myConnection.Open();

string query = "SELECT field1,field2,field3,field4, field5,field6,field7,field8 FROM [dbo].[Staff] WHERE  Email=@email AND CompanyId = @companyId";

SqlCommand getStaff = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

getStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
getStaff.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyId", companyId);

SqlDataReader reader = getStaff.ExecuteReader();
StaffBLL staff = new StaffBLL();

try
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        staff.field1 = reader[0].ToString();
        staff.Name = reader[1].ToString();
        staff.field3 = reader[2].ToString();
        staff.field4 = reader[3].ToString();
        staff.field5 = reader[4].ToString();
        staff.field6 = reader[5].ToString();
        staff.field7 = Convert.ToInt32(reader[6]);
        staff.field8 = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[7]);
    }

    reader.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
myConnection.Close();
```

I have changed most of the field names on purpose

**Edit 2**
Tried more debugging

So when i try to debug and added a break point in the page load and if i run two sessions at the same time, i am stopped at the break point for both sessions and the cookie data is unique for each but once i hit continue for both, the cookie data to whatever the second request is, is used for both the sessions. you can view the user id's in both screenshots
[image: First hit]

[image: Second hit]

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I copy and pasted wrong. I have updated with some edits and added the right code. I know it was pointless in that manner. : )

Comment: What do you mean by "Whenever I run two instances of localhost, and I click on the same page together, data from different company id is being shown to me." please provide more detail on what you are actually doing.

Comment: Does the problem occur if you use two different browsers, rather than just one?

Comment: I am using different browsers and supposeI have two companies A and B and i click to view projects page on both sessions at same time, the projects associated to usually company A are visible on both sessions. Actually session 1 should show company A m’s projects and session 2 should show company B’s projects

Comment: Is `logB` shared or static?

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and [AddWithValue is Evil](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: LogB is shared.